# How to achieve Parallelism in LibreTranslate

Tags: python, node.js, libreoffice, language-translation

We are using Python LibreTranslate and calling it in Node.js microservice.
But the calls to translation service is one by one (inside a loop) , which is taking time to translate entire web page.

Is there any way we can parallelly send and receive translation or any other way which can improve translation time.

Comment: you can use Python concurrent.futures module to perform multiple translation request